# json format for user data using firebase

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase for my android app. I have following structure for the users data in json:

```
     {  "employee":
        {
          "empone" : {
            "id" : "11",
            "name" : "emponeone"
          },
          "emptwo" : {
            "id" : 10,
            "name" : "emptwo"
          }
        }
}
```

I am trying to get names of all the employee in my arrylist. But when I am reading the data from firebase I am getting the employee reference in Datasnapshot object which I am not able to store into my jsonObject. I tried following :

```
String data1= String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
```

But this gives me the data in following format :

```
  data1= {empone={name=emponeone, id=11}, emptwo={name=emptwo, id=10}}
```

Is there anyway so that I can get only the name field in my arraylist or any other format to get the employee structure just the way I want it?

Comment: Can you show a **complete** snippet that reproduces the problem? Right now there is no way for us to know what the `dataSnapshot` refers to, which makes it hard to help.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/). It has good examples and explanation.

You'll need a class `Employee` with a string named `name`, an int or string named `id` (since you mix those two in your example, I don't know.)
Lastly, convert it like this:

```
class Employee {
     String name;
     String id;

     public Employee(){
         //needed for the getValue() method
     }

     //getters, setters, constructors 
}



// Get Employee object and use the values to update the UI
Employee employee = dataSnapshot.getValue(Employee.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

The output you are getting is the output from a Java map as described here: [AbstractMap#toString](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/AbstractMap.html#toString()).

To get the output as JSON, you can convert a Map to JSON with

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject((Map)dataSnapshot.getValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I simulated your problem on my machine. I created the exact database in Firebase Realtime Database and tried to read it. 
[image]

And I figured out that there are two possible solutions for two different situations.

1. When you know the name of objects (in this case the **empone** and **emptwo**)

In that case, you can just need to convert datasnapshot into JSONObject and then access the each object by its name.

```
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    reference = reference.child("employee");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject((Map) dataSnapshot.getValue());
            try {

                JSONObject empone = jsonObject.getJSONObject("empone");
                String name = empone.getString("name");
                JSONObject emptwo = jsonObject.getJSONObject("emptwo");
                String name2 = empone.getString("name");
                Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: name: " + name);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: JSON Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: database error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });

}
```

It is a tedious and not-recommended way but it does solve the problem you mention

2. When you don't know the name and number of projects.
   In this case, you need to create a model class for the JSONObjects.
   Assign each JSONObject to that model class and iterate through the Data snapshot
   Like this:

   ```
   FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   DatabaseReference reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
   reference = reference.child("employee");
   reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               //Getting User object from dataSnapshot
               Employee employee = data.getValue(Employee.class);
               Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange:  empname: " + employee.getName());
           }

       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
           Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: database error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
       }
   });
   ```

This is a recommended way to get the thing job done with little information!

You can [read completely about Firebase Database](https://firebasetutorials.com/firebase-database), starting from introduction to JSON to deleting files from Firestore all at one place!

Answer (score 0):

you dataSnapShot should have children, you should iterate through them:

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshotChild : snapshot.getChildren())
```

and parse the children using an `employee.class` which would describe an employee as A java Bean class using `snapshotChild.getValue(employee.class)` from there you can retrieve the name using your get function of your bean class.